# Are multiple calls to string.Replace() less efficient than a single call to a Regex method in .NET?

Tags: .net

I want to replace about 8 characters in a string.

Would it be more efficient to use a Regex method or just use multiple calls to string.Replace()

I'm replacing about 7 characters that may appear, all to be underscores instead. The characters could appear anywhere in the string, and not in a particular order etc.

Comment: Whichever is faster, `Regex.Replace` seems like the more readable solution.

Comment: why not do a benchmark on your own? (if that is all about)

Comment: +1 to Yuriy for the emphasis on readability.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Don't use the Regex class unless you actually need to match a regular expression.  It's much more efficient to let the String type do straight text or character matching if that's all your doing than to create a Regex.

The Regex class is much more powerful than simple character or string matching.  This power does not come for free.  Using a full regex to match a character / string is overkill.  It's the equivalent of using a high power explosive to remove a single ant from your lawn when your shoe would do just fine.

Answer (score 8):

**You don't need to make multiple calls to `string.Replace()`** - it replaces all occurences in a single pass. [See the MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1.aspx). You only need to make multiple calls if you are replacing different input sequences within the string (which may be what you're implying in your question).

In that case, I would use `string.Split` and `string.Join` for this:

```
var replaced = string.Join( "_", input.Split( new[]{'x','y','z'} ) );
```

This will split the string at every location where one of the characters 'x', 'y', or 'z' occurs (replace with your set) and will rejoin the fragments using the '_' character -- effectively replacing the originals. This approach is **NOT** necessarily more efficient than multiple calls to `string.Replace` - that would depend on the length of the input string, the number of occurences of the characters to replace, and so on. You would need to do profiling with real-world data to determine what is faster. What this approach *does do*, however, is make the code more concise.

As far as performance is concerned - I would go with the simplest and most readable solution first, and if *testing demonstrates a problem* - then I would profile and decide what alternative solutions to pursue (if any). Unless there are strong reasons to do otherwise, my personal priorities when writing code are:

1. Make it correct.
2. Make it clear.
3. Make it concise.
4. Make it fast.
5. .. In that order.

Comment: Multiple calls for multiple characters

Comment: Hi LBushkin - The reason I need to call it multiple times is that I need to replace a few different characters for example # or /

Each call will replace all of one particular character, but I have various different characters to replace.

Comment: @Dan Harris: Unless you are in a truly high volume scenario, I would use something like `string.Split / string.Join` to do this work. I find it concise and easy to understand.

Comment: @Dan - what he's describing will replace all of the characters in one pass; no need to call it multiple times.

Comment: @LBushkin: You used a closing parenthesis rather than a closing bracket on your array.

Comment: Is there any way to split on multiple delimiters and find out which lines were separated by which delimiters?

Comment: @supercat: Sure, split the string and rejoin with some known character (e.g. '_'). Then compare the rejoined string with the original to see which segments were delimited by which characters - you can do so using LINQ since strings are treated as sequences of characters: `original.Except( rejoined )`

Answer (score 4):

At the same time, depending on how long these strings may be and how many characters may need to be replaced, you should use a StringBuilder object rather than a string.

Strings are immutable, so in each replacement you'd be creating a new string with the underscore. The StringBuilder class is more efficient for multiple changes to a string object.

Comment: Nice tip on using StringBuilder

Answer (score 1):

12 ticks vs 1200 ticks vs 40 ticks

```
public class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string str = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvxywz0123456789_";
        string replace = "aez01234567";

        DoReplace(str, replace); // 12
        DoRegex(str, replace);   // 1200
        DoJoin(str, replace);    // 40

        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    public static void DoReplace(string str, string replace)
    {
        Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
        sw.Start();
        for (int i = 0; i < replace.Length; ++i)
        {
            str = str.Replace(replace[i], '*');
        }
        sw.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("Multiple replace (" + sw.ElapsedTicks + ") => " + str);
    }

    public static void DoRegex(string str, string replace)
    {
        Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
        sw.Start();
        str = Regex.Replace(str, "[" + replace + "]", "*");
        sw.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("Regex replace (" + sw.ElapsedTicks + ") => " + str);
    }

    public static void DoJoin(string str, string replace)
    {
        Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
        sw.Start();
        str = string.Join("*", str.Split(replace.ToCharArray()));
        sw.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("Join replace (" + sw.ElapsedTicks + ") => " + str);
    }
}
```

I guess the simple replace in a loop is faster...

**UPDATE**
Included LBushkin's method

Answer (score 0):

without actually profiling it, i'd say using the regex is faster, since the string is only looped once. i guess each string.replace loops the whole string once

```
yourString = Regex.Replace(yourString, @"[uiae]", @"_"); // replace u, i, a and e with an underscore
```

Comment: Your answer may be correct, but your code is wrong on many levels.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on [LoneDeveloper's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3239158/are-multiple-calls-to-string-replace-less-efficient-than-a-single-call-to-a-re/3239241#3239241), you could write your own extension method to make a bunch of replacements at once:

```
public static ReplaceAll(this string text, IEnumerable<string> needles, string replacement)
{
    var sb = new StringBuilder(text);
    foreach (string needle in needles)
    {
        sb.Replace(needle, replacement);
    }

    return sb.ToString();
}
```

To call this code, you'd just do something like this:

```
var needles = new string[] { "a", "b", "c" };

string abcRemoved = "abcdefg".ReplaceAll(needles, "_");
```