# Regex for multiple lines checking

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying out regex (`import re`) to extract the info I want from a log file.

UPDATE: Added the `C:\WINDOWS\security` folder permissions which broke all of the sample codes.

Say the format of the log is:

```
C:\:
    BUILTIN\Administrators  Allowed:    Full Control
    NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM Allowed:    Full Control
    BUILTIN\Users   Allowed:    Read & Execute
    BUILTIN\Users   Allowed:    Special Permissions: 
            Create Folders
    BUILTIN\Users   Allowed:    Special Permissions: 
            Create Files
    \Everyone   Allowed:    Read & Execute
    (No auditing)

C:\WINDOWS\system32:
    BUILTIN\Users   Allowed:    Read & Execute
    BUILTIN\Power Users Allowed:    Modify
    BUILTIN\Power Users Allowed:    Special Permissions: 
            Delete
    BUILTIN\Administrators  Allowed:    Full Control
    NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM Allowed:    Full Control
    (No auditing)

C:\WINDOWS\system32\config:
    BUILTIN\Users   Allowed:    Read & Execute
    BUILTIN\Power Users Allowed:    Read & Execute
    BUILTIN\Administrators  Allowed:    Full Control
    NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM Allowed:    Full Control
    (No auditing)

C:\WINDOWS\security:
    BUILTIN\Users   Allowed:    Special Permissions: 
            Traverse Folder
            Read Attributes
            Read Permissions
    BUILTIN\Power Users Allowed:    Special Permissions: 
            Traverse Folder
            Read Attributes
            Read Permissions
    BUILTIN\Administrators  Allowed:    Full Control
    NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM Allowed:    Full Control
    (No auditing)
```

And it repeats for a few other directories. How can I split them into `paragraphs` and then check for lines containing `Special Permissions:`?

Like this:

1. Separate the whole string1 into few parts, `C:\` and `C:\WINDOWS\system32`.
2. Look in each line that contains 'Special Permissions:'
3. Display the whole line, e.g.:
   `C:\:`
   `BUILTIN\Users   Allowed:    Special Permissions: \n\`
   `Create Folders\n\`
   `BUILTIN\Users   Allowed:    Special Permissions: \n\`
   `Create Files\n\`
4. Repeat for next 'paragraph'

I was thinking of:
1. Search the whole text file for `r"(\w+:\\)(\w+\\?)*:"` - return me the path
2. String function or regex to get the rest of the output
3. Remove all the other lines besides the ones with `Special Permissions`
4. Display, and repeat step 1

But I think it is not efficient.

Can anyone guide me on this? Thanks.

---

Example output:

```
C:\:
BUILTIN\Users   Allowed:    Special Permissions:
Create Folders
BUILTIN\Users   Allowed:    Special Permissions:
Create Files

C:\WINDOWS\system32:
BUILTIN\Power Users Allowed:    Special Permissions: 
Delete

C:\WINDOWS\security:
BUILTIN\Users   Allowed:    Special Permissions: 
Traverse Folder
Read Attributes
Read Permissions
BUILTIN\Power Users Allowed:    Special Permissions: 
Traverse Folder
Read Attributes
Read Permissions
```

`C:\WINDOWS\system32\config` doesn't show up as there's no Special Permission in the lines.

---

The template I am using:

```
import re

text = ""

def main():
    f = open('DirectoryPermissions.xls', 'r')
    global text
    for line in f:
        text = text + line
    f.close
    print text

def regex():
    global text
    <insert code here>

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
    regex()
```

---

Comment: Use the `re` module, not `regex`. Also, look into triple-quoted strings.

Comment: What data do you want at the end?

Comment: @nmichaels, Lol I'll edit, I am using `import re`
@MattH - To show the full line(s) containing `Special Permissions:` in each path

Comment: The first thing you should do is work on a line-by-line basis using file.readline() or file.readlines(). You can find the lines that begin the sections and the entries without using regular expressions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to `milkypostman`, `scoffey`, and the rest I came up with the solution:

```
def regex():
    global text
    for paragraph in text.split('\n\n'):
        lines = paragraph.split('\n', 1)
        #personal modifier to choose certain output only
        if lines[0].startswith('C:\\:') or lines[0].startswith('C:\\WINDOWS\system32:') or lines[0].startswith('C:\\WINDOWS\\security:'):
            print lines[0]
            iterables = re.finditer(r".*Special Permissions: \n(\s+[a-zA-Z ]+\n)*", lines[1])
            for items in iterables:
                #cosmetic fix
                parsedText = re.sub(r"\n$", "", items.group(0))
                parsedText = re.sub(r"^\s+", "", parsedText)
                parsedText = re.sub(r"\n\s+", "\n", parsedText)
                print parsedText
            print
```

I will still go through all of the posted codes (esp. scoffey's as I never knew pure string manipulation is that powerful). Thanks for the insight!

Of course, this will not be the most optimal, but it works for my case. If you have any suggestions, do feel free to post.

---

Output:

```
C:\Python27>openfile.py
C:\:
BUILTIN\Users   Allowed:        Special Permissions:
Create Folders
BUILTIN\Users   Allowed:        Special Permissions:
Create Files

C:\WINDOWS\security:
BUILTIN\Users   Allowed:        Special Permissions:
Traverse Folder
Read Attributes
Read Permissions
BUILTIN\Power Users     Allowed:        Special Permissions:
Traverse Folder
Read Attributes
Read Permissions

C:\WINDOWS\system32:
BUILTIN\Power Users     Allowed:        Special Permissions:
Delete
```

Answer (score 2):

```
# I would replace this with reading lines from a file,
# rather than splitting a big string containing the file.

section = None
inspecialperm = False
with open("testdata.txt") as w:
    for line in w:
        if not line.startswith("            "):
            inspecialperm = False

        if section is None:
            section = line

        elif len(line) == 0:
            section = None

        elif 'Special Permissions' in line:
            if section:
                print section
                section = ""
            inspecialperm = True
            print line,

        elif inspecialperm:
            print line,
```

Comment: I tried your code, it works partly, correctly selecting those Special Permissions, but does not print the permissions themselves. I'll try to fiddle around with it.

Comment: I updated it a bit.  Now it doesn't print section headers if they don't have a "Special Permissions" line and it should print the permissions.  If you don't want the tabs printed, just do a strip on them before you print them.

Comment: What is wrong with it?  I put your text into a file and then ran the code, it worked good.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the `re` module at all if you parse strings by "split & strip", which is more efficient:

```
for paragraph in string1.split('\n\n'):
    path = paragraph.split('\n', 1)[0].strip().rstrip(':')
    paragraph = paragraph.replace(': \n', ': ') # hack to have permissions in same line
    for line in paragraph.split('\n'):
        if 'Special Permissions: ' in line:
            permission = line.rsplit(':', 1)[-1].strip()
            print 'Path "%s" has special permission "%s"' % (path, permission)
```

Replace the `print` statement with whatever fits your needs.

**EDIT:** As pointed out in the comment, the previous solution doesn't work with the new input lines in the edited question, but here's how to fix it (still more efficiently than using regular expressions):

```
for paragraph in string1.split('\n\n'):
    path = paragraph.split('\n', 1)[0].strip().rstrip(':')
    owner = None
    for line in paragraph.split('\n'):
        if owner is not None and ':' not in line:
            permission = line.rsplit(':', 1)[-1].strip()
            print 'Owner "%s" has special permission "%s" on path "%s"' % (owner, permission, path)
        else:
            owner = line.split(' Allowed:', 1)[0].strip() if line.endswith('Special Permissions: ') else None
```

Comment: Your code somehow breaks when presented with: C:\WINDOWS\security:
 BUILTIN\Users Allowed:  Special Permissions: 
   Traverse Folder
   Read Attributes
   Read Permissions

Comment: True. It was meant to parse the original input string before editing the question. Now I updated the solution to match the last case too.

Comment: Interesting. Works well. Thanks. Never really understand your code until I came out with mine. But your approach is much more flexible as you can manipulate how you want it to be printed. I don't understand the [-1] in your rsplit though.

Comment: The `rsplit` method is the same as `split` but starting from right. The second optional argument of these methods determines how many times the string is to be split into parts. So, for example, `line.rsplit(':', 1)[-1]` splits the line into two parts, in the rightmost ":", and keeps the last part. Anyway, I just realized that in this new version, that statement can be simplified to `permission = line.strip()` :P

Comment: Hmm so the `rsplit(':', 1)[-1]` is redundant? Haha. Anyway, just a note: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3610660/string-manipulation-vs-regexps Guess the performance issue is not really an issue with regex =D

Comment: Yes, that part is redundant. Regarding performance: Note that those answers do not deny that using a regex is less efficient. See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3239158/ . It is true that a compiled regex can be fast. But simple splits and replacements will still be much faster, especially on short strings. Anyway, I guess performance isn't an issue in your case, so you should give priority to readability. Some people argue that using a regex is more "declarative" and general. But I like splits because they divide the big problem in small parts, easy to solve. That's elegant.

Comment: +1 for the great explanation and the example. =D Yea to me regex seems more straight forward as sometimes split I will need to think what was I trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to milkypostman's solution, but in the format you are trying to have that output in:

```
lines=string1.splitlines()
seperator = None
for index, line in enumerate(lines):
    if line == "":
        seperator = line
    elif "Special Permissions" in line:
        if seperator != None:
            print seperator
        print line.lstrip()
        offset=0
        while True:
            #if the line's last 2 characters are ": "
            if lines[index+offset][-2:]==": ":
                print lines[index+offset+1].lstrip()
                offset+=1
            else:
                break
```

Comment: Hi, I tried this code, but I can't get it to work, it keeps printing "Create Folders" and I have to manually terminate it. What went wrong?

Comment: My mistake. Sorry. Fixed now.

Comment: Wow your logic is coded so differently compared to others. Anyway, nice try as you get the special permissions correct but it doesn't print out their respective directories.

Comment: I'm sorry. I can't believe I didn't look carefully at those instructions. The fix is to simply replace seperator = line with seperator = line + "\n" + lines[index+1]

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using the `re` module and the`findall` method.

```
data = '''\
C:\:
    BUILTIN\Administrators  Allowed:    Full Control
    NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM Allowed:    Full Control 
    BUILTIN\Users   Allowed:    Read & Execute
    BUILTIN\Users   Allowed:    Special Permissions: 
            Create Folders
    BUILTIN\Users   Allowed:    Special Permissions: 
            Create Files
    \Everyone   Allowed:    Read & Execute
    (No auditing)

C:\WINDOWS\system32:
    BUILTIN\Users   Allowed:    Read & Execute
    BUILTIN\Power Users Allowed:    Modify
    BUILTIN\Power Users Allowed:    Special Permissions: 
            Delete
    BUILTIN\Administrators  Allowed:    Full Control
    NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM Allowed:    Full Control
    (No auditing)

C:\WINDOWS\system32\config:
    BUILTIN\Users   Allowed:    Read & Execute
    BUILTIN\Power Users Allowed:    Read & Execute
    BUILTIN\Administrators  Allowed:    Full Control
    NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM Allowed:    Full Control
    (No auditing)
'''

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import re

    # A regular expression to match a section "C:...."
    cre_par = re.compile(r'''
                ^C:.*?
                ^\s*$''', re.DOTALL | re.MULTILINE | re.VERBOSE)

    # A regular expression to match a "Special Permissions" line, and the
    # following line.
    cre_permissions = re.compile(r'''(^.*Special\ Permissions:\s*\n.*)\n''', 
                                re.MULTILINE | re.VERBOSE)

    # Create list of strings to output.
    out = []
    for t in cre_par.findall(data):
        out += [t[:t.find('\n')]] + cre_permissions.findall(data) + ['']

    # Join output list of strings together using end-of-line character
    print '\n'.join(out)
```

Here is the generated output:

```
C:\:
    BUILTIN\Users   Allowed:    Special Permissions: 
            Create Folders
    BUILTIN\Users   Allowed:    Special Permissions: 
            Create Files
    BUILTIN\Power Users Allowed:    Special Permissions: 
            Delete

C:\WINDOWS\system32:
    BUILTIN\Users   Allowed:    Special Permissions: 
            Create Folders
    BUILTIN\Users   Allowed:    Special Permissions: 
            Create Files
    BUILTIN\Power Users Allowed:    Special Permissions: 
            Delete

C:\WINDOWS\system32\config:
    BUILTIN\Users   Allowed:    Special Permissions: 
            Create Folders
    BUILTIN\Users   Allowed:    Special Permissions: 
            Create Files
    BUILTIN\Power Users Allowed:    Special Permissions: 
            Delete
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the code but, the output is wrong. `system32\config` should not appear, and there's only `Special Permissions: Delete` for `system32`. The `C:\:` should have `Create Files and Folders` only. Nevertheless I'll look into your code later too. Thanks again